# Retrieve child data of a node with XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I want to retrieve the data of the **DESCRIPTION** child.

***Here is my XML*** :

```
<RETURN type="object">
    <DESCRIPTION>Objet créé</DESCRIPTION>
</RETURN>
```

And i tried to retrive the data of **DESCRIPTION** like this, but it doesn't seems to work :

```
<xsl:for-each select="RETURN">
    <xsl:for-each select="DESCRIPTION">
        <DIV>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
        </DIV>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I'm using XSLT 1.0. Thank again

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, i fixed it like this :

```
<xsl:for-each select="RETURN">
    <DIV>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="./DESCRIPTION"/>
    </DIV>
</xsl:for-each>
```